# php : good way to use a function for multiples variable

Tags: php, refactoring

I wonder is there a good way to refactor this simple problem, without using round each line, or a foreach... :

```
<?php
$x =1,999999;
$y = 3.1562;
$z = 4.433232;

$x = round($x);
$y = round($y);
$z = round($z);


?>
```

Edit : Of course, without using immediatly $x = round(1.9999). (it's just used for the example).

Comment: I dont understand for what you can use it that. Can you write an example?

Comment: this question is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes. `$x=2; $y=3; $z=4;` simple refactoring

Comment: Smart Riggs. But not useful.